# Pyspark remote application taking too long to respond

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark cluster on which I am running pyspark. I am trying to remotely create a spark application using pyspark and read a csv file which is just 8 Mb (for the purpose of testing spark). The application is being successfully created, but the read csv takes a long time. I waited for upto 4 hours and still the line of code was running. The code looks like this :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("RemoteSparkApp") .master("spark://ip") .getOrCreate()
```

`df = spark.read.csv(r"location\cities.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)`

I am able to see the created application in the dashboard. And my cluster has 3 workers (72 CPUs and 96 Gb RAM). But reading the file locally on the master machine using pyspark works fine.